# Unable to load bootstrap icons on http://

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> "Font from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access."

Getting this error when page delivered from http://example.com. http://www.example.com works fine. All bootstrap's files stored locally.
Is this a server bug?

UPD This is how files are included

```
<link href="catalog/view/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4-autocomplete/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="catalog/view/theme/js/common.js"></script>
```

UPD: solved by changing base domain in the `<base>` metatag

```
<base href="http://example.com"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `www.example.com` and `example.com` are different origins — even if you host the same website on each of them.

- Avoid using absolute URIs in your code
- Pick one of the two hostnames to be canonical and configure the other one to redirect to it.

Comment: there'are relative URLs

Comment: You haven't shared your code, but your error message says they are not.

Comment: Where do I need to set canonical URL? Did you mean canonical metatag?

Comment: No. I mean canonical as per the English definition. You don't need a meta tag if you have a redirect from the non-canonical URL to the canonical one. because then the non-canonical one will never have content of its own to be indexed by search engines, they get redirected.